# Alias en host virtual en Xampp de proyecto en Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, virtualhost

Actualmente tengo un proyecto creado en Laravel 5.6, cree un host virtual para poder acceder mediante la url `proyecto.com:8003` . Aparentemente para poder acceder a mi proyecto debo colocar el puerto al final de la URL debido a que no es el puerto por defecto (80). Quiero colocarle un alias de manera que no se tenga que incluir el puerto al final de la url sino simplemente acceder con `proyecto.com`

Comment: Para eso tienes que modificar el archivo hosts de tu SO [aquí un enlace](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) para saber donde se encuentra dicho archivo dependiento a tu SO

Comment: Ok, ¿Que deberia agregarle agregarle? Ya lo habia modificado antes para colocarle el host virtual agregando `127.0.0.1    proyecto.com`

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8003 proyecto.com` en el caso de tu puerto en especifico

Comment: Agregue eso tendria esto en el archivo hosts:
`127.0.0.1 proyecto.com
127.0.0.1:8003 proyecto.com`
Intente ingresar luego de reiniciar el apache, pero no entra ¿No deberia modificar algo en el xampp?

Comment: Elimina el de `127.0.0.1 proyecto` porque los dos estan accediendo a lo mismo, entra en conflicto

Comment: Nada, no me deja acceder ahora ni siquiera colocando la url con el puerto al final.

Comment: como accedes a tu proyecto?, al final solo debes tipear **proyecto.com** sin el puerto en el navegador

Comment: Primero lo agregue al archivo hosts de Windows como 127.0.0.1 proyecto.com, luego cambie el puerto en Listen en el archivo httpd.conf de apache en xampp por 8003, luego agregue el virtual host en httpd-vhosts con el puerto 8003

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es poniendo un comando en CMD de Windows (como administrador):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.2.2.2 connectport=8003 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Lo que hace ese comando es avisarle a Windows que si hay alguna petición a 127.2.2.2:80 redireccione esa petición a 127.0.0.1:8003 (según el puerto que pusiste), es configuración interna de Windows.

OJO: Tienes que cambiar la configuración en el archivo `hosts` de Windows con la IP que pongas en `listenaddress`. En el archivo de host virtual de Apache sólo tienes que dejarlo como `<VirtualHost *:8003>`